# Android Studio. Activity class not called when the activity included by <include/> tag

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm a newbie with Android development and I have a problem.

I created the Empty Activity project which become main. Next I added second activity - Google Maps. Next I include the maps activity into the main activity with the `<include/>` tag:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/activity_maps" />
```

When I start my app, the maps activity is shown, but no methods called in the  automatically generated `MapsActivity` class. Its code is:

```
package com.example.work.myapplication3;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setMessage("Message");
        ad.create().show();    
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I added the message box to see when the `onCreate` method is called. But it never called, while the map is shown on the screen.

I want to create several activities with its own classes incapsulating its logic. But at this point I can create subactivities, but can't use its classes. I want automatically created activity's class to be executed when I include this activity into another one.

What I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That's not what include does.  It doesn't include an activity, it includes a layout.  Its like copy pasting the contents of that layout file at that location.  There is no way to include an activity as a sub-activity, that's kind of what Fragments are for.

Comment: So how to create a fragment with its own class and its own XML and then include it in an activity?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: When I try to add an automatically generated Empty Fragment my app just crashes...